# Can I reuse a recommendation letter that was given to me a year ago for PhD applications now?

Tags: phd, graduate-admissions, united-states, recommendation-letter

I took a recommendation letter from one of my Professor last year and I want to apply for a PhD position now.Is it OK if I send that recommendation letter or should I ask for a new one?

Comment: I assume you are in a country whose academic culture allows you to have the recommendation letter in the first place.  The American version of this question is "Can I use someone as a reference in my PhD applications now if they wrote me a recommendation letter a year ago?"  And the answer is "Yes, but you **must** ask them first.  And they'll probably want to revise their old letter."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Would you send a CV that's a year old?

You have hopefully been doing something in the time between when your professor wrote the letter and now. Your reference letter should reflect that. If you can, ask them for a new one, otherwise find someone who you've been working with more recently to ask.

Comment: No I will send an updated CV.But I have to send three recommendation letters thats why I was asking.If I ask him again he will write the same thing,right?

Comment: If you haven't contacted him or worked with him since when he last wrote the letter, then I imagine he would write exactly the same thing, unless the letter was not tailored towards a PhD application (eg emphasising your research ability), in which case he might conceivably edit it.

Comment: Yes,it was for a PhD position.I took it but eventually I did not apply that time.And he emphasized everything very well in it,I mean its a good and strong letter indeed.

Comment: In that case, I'd say reuse it. Good luck with your application! `:)`

Comment: So u mean to say date is not a problem at all?

Comment: Truthfully, I don't know. It's a little deceitful to put today's date on a year old letter, but if the admissions committee see a year-old letter they will likely question why you haven't updated it. In my opinion, the best course of action would be to contact your professor and ask if he minds you changing the date to a more recent one. Or, to avoid this, ask him for a brand new letter.